# Accessing the last page on Google search results

Tags: search

Currently am only able to access few pages on Google search result. For example, I saw "Page 18 of about 174 results (0.89 seconds)" on my search but I can't access beyond the 18th page.

[image]

How do I access pages beyong the 18th page to the very last page (174th in this case)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Page 18 of about 174 results" does not mean that there are 174 pages of results; it means that there are 174 individual results, which in this case take up 18 pages.

You can't go beyond the 18th page because there are only 18 pages of results.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of an internet mystery. Initially, when you search something you will see a message like "About 5,000,000 results" or something, but if you keep going to the next page eventually you will hit the end and see a much smaller results number. It wasn't always this way and many people remember going a thousand pages in and seeing what was there. Ben's answer is correct, but when you search Kumasi in Google you don't see 174 results, you see 17,100,000 results, and it isn't until page 18 you see that there aren't actually that many results. It's unclear as to whether this is intentional deception or some optimization quirk. There is some more information on a stackexchange post as well.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14972/why-on-the-first-page-google-says-there-are-thousands-of-results-but-on-the-last